# RewriteRule question

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteRule oferte-cel-mai-bun-pret(-(apartamente|garsoniere|case|vile|birouri|spatii-comerciale|spatii-industriale|mini-hoteluri-pensiuni|ferme|proprietati-speciale|terenuri-intravilane|terenuri-extravilane))?(-(([0-9+])-([a-z-+]+)+))?-(vanzare|inchiriere)/([a-z-+]+)(/pagina-(([0-9]+)+))?(/)?$ index.php?seo[]=anunturi&tip_categorie=$2&nr=$5&tip_numar=$6&cmbp_$7=1&tip_cautare=$7&judet=$8&pagina=$9 [L,QSA]
```

I have this RewriteRule, and this url: http://site/oferte-cel-mai-bun-pret-vile-1-etaj-vanzare/bucuresti/pagina-2/

All parameters are ok untill last one about page, i receive:

```
Array
(
    [seo] => Array
        (
            [0] => anunturi
        )

    [tip_categorie] => vile
    [nr] => 1
    [tip_numar] => etaj
    [cmbp_vanzare] => 1
    [tip_cautare] => vanzare
    [judet] => bucuresti
    [pagina] => /pagina-2
)
```

`[pagina] => /pagina-2` - i want here to return only page number if isset in url.. if not to return it blank..

Problem is here .. &pagina=$9 :| I can`t put $10 as a parameter? more than 9... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to group every single atom in your pattern. For example, `(-(([0-9+])-([a-z-+]+)+))?` can probably be reduced to `(-([0-9+])-([a-z-+]+))?`:

```
RewriteRule\
    ^oferte-cel-mai-bun-pret(-(apartamente|garsoniere|case|vile|birouri|spatii-comerciale|spatii-industriale|mini-hoteluri-pensiuni|ferme|proprietati-speciale|terenuri-intravilane|terenuri-extravilane))?(-([0-9+])-([a-z-+]+))?-(vanzare|inchiriere)/([a-z-+]+)(/pagina-([0-9]+))?/?$\
    index.php?seo[]=anunturi&tip_categorie=$2&nr=$4&tip_numar=$5&cmbp_$6=1&tip_cautare=$6&judet=$7&pagina=$9 [L,QSA]
```

With this you can reduce 12 groups to just 9.

And if you are using Apache 2, you can use non-capturing groups `(?:…)` instead of normal groups `(…)`. The matches of non-caputring groups cannot be referenced. So use normal groups for everything that you want to be able reference and use non-capturing groups for everything else:

```
RewriteRule\
    ^oferte-cel-mai-bun-pret(?:-(apartamente|garsoniere|case|vile|birouri|spatii-comerciale|spatii-industriale|mini-hoteluri-pensiuni|ferme|proprietati-speciale|terenuri-intravilane|terenuri-extravilane))?(?:-([0-9+])-([a-z-+]+))?-(vanzare|inchiriere)/([a-z-+]+)(?:/pagina-([0-9]+))?/?$\
    index.php?seo[]=anunturi&tip_categorie=$1&nr=$2&tip_numar=$3&cmbp_$4=1&tip_cautare=$4&judet=$5&pagina=$6 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

`pagina=$10` instead of `pagina=$9` ?