# Regex negative prefix and suffix

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I have these strings for example:

```
download-google-chrome-free
download-mozilla-firefox-free
```

And also these strings:

```
google-chrome
mozilla-firefox
```

My prefix is ​​`download-` and my suffix is ​​`-free`, I need a regular expression to capture the words `google-chrome`, If the input string does not have `download-` and `-free` prefix and suffix, the group captured is the string itself.

String 1 = download-google-chrome-free (with prefix and sufix)

```
String 1 Group 1 = download-
String 1 Group 2 = google-chrome
String 1 Group 3 = -free
```

String 2 = google-chrome (without prefix and sufix)

```
String 2 Group 1 = '' (empty)
String 2 Group 2 = google-chrome (empty)
String 2 Group 3 = '' (empty)
```

You can do that? I am using `PHP` using `preg_match`.

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for assertions.

Comment: you can try this

`$a="google-chrome-free";
preg_match("/(?:\w+-)?(\w+-\w+)(?:-\w+)?/",$a,$match);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(download-)?(google-chrome|mozilla-firefox)(-free)?/', $string, $match);
```

The `?` indicates that the group before it is optional. If the prefix or suffix isn't in the string, those capture groups will be empty in `$match`.

If you don't actually want to return the groups with the optional prefix and suffix, make them non-capturing groups by putting `?:` at the beginning of the group:

```
preg_match('/(?:download-)?(google-chrome|mozilla-firefox)(?:-free)?/', $string, $match);
```

Now `$match[1]` will contain the browser name that you want.

Comment: you could tell him, that $match[2] will capture what he wants, since match[1] is "download"

Comment: He wants all 3, according to his example.

Comment: so i misunderstood it - "I need a regular expression to capture the words **google-chrome**, If the input string **does not have download- and -free prefix and suffix**, the group captured is the string itself."

Comment: He clearly has English language problems (he's Brazilian). I went by the examples of the output that he wants.

Comment: Sorry for the errors of English, used an automatic translator. Thanks for the reply Barmar, your answer is right, but for my case it does not serve the response Sirius_Black're right, this is exactly what I need, outcomes and responses are similar, but the Sirius_Black is more correct to me, because the groups that I do not want to be deleted, and produce the same number of groups with and without prefix.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show non-capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks, I tested is now perfect, friend, thank you very much, it was just what I needed, I performed all the possibilities and the result is always the same really, is correct.

Comment: This type of regular expression, also works in htaccess files??

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4041573/1491895 Apache 2 supports non-capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks again, I also perform the tests on Apache now.